# High chart with diffrent series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a chart with different series data. I have a poll with several question and every question has different options.
I tried to use this code :

```
$(function () {
$('#c_chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Question 1',
            'Question 2',
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: [['Option1', 'Option2']],
        data: [49.9, 56]

    }, {
        name: 'Option3',
        data: [83.6]

    }
    ]

});});
```

How can I create this chart like following image:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pskTX.jpg)

Comment: How about 1 series per option? Then just fill in the values for that option, per question, in `data`.

Comment: @HalvorStrand How can I do this ? :)

Comment: You can use x index per each point, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/29wws4bt/, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

my english is basic but, i try to splain rigth?

try to look this links, im not very sure if you need to move something in plotOptions:{} or chart:{}

the other options not draw the chart. i found this links, i'll hope help you

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels

grettins, from mexico :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Questions Answers'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Question1', 'Question2', 'Question3', 'Question4', 'Question5']
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Option Ticked'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>';
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Option1',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Option2',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }, {
        name: 'Option3',
        data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Option4',
        data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3]
    }]
});
```

});